# How to make a volume fade from center in Blender 2.8?

Tags: volumetrics

I've come across COUNTLESS different tutorials to make this work in older versions of blender. I am attempting to create a rayleigh scattering effect at the edges of planets viewed from space. I have followed youtube tutorials, and even bought that Space VFX class for 60 bucks hoping for an answer. The old way to do it was quite simple as shown below :[image]

Note : the default values the tutorials all use are all roughly 1. i just used this screenshot to show it didnt work, even when values were cranked to extremes. If anyone knows how to work around this or a better method, i would be eternally grateful!

Answer (score 1):

On going from Gradient Texture node to Math node (using Multiply) you have a multiplication factor of 0. Hence the strength of the emission will be 0. Here is a node setup that seems to work

[image]